# C# Service Timed to Fetch Data

Tags: c#, service, timer, copy, timed

I need to create a service to install on a local PC that is going to look to a file path on my server periodically and copy and paste it's contents to a destination on a local PC.  I want to set it to run every six or twelve hours or so.  I also need it to run the copy command with elevated credentials as well.  We can't use scheduled tasks because our Group Policy disables those due to a virus.  Below is what I have so far, it isn't much.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

namespace PHSReportUpdater
{
  public class Timer1
  {
      private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

      public static void Main()
      {
          // Create a timer with an interval
          aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(600000);

          // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer
          aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

          // Set the Interval
          aTimer.Interval = 21600000;
          aTimer.Enabled = true;
      }

      private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
          string reportSource;
          string reportDest;
          reportSource= @"V:\PrivateFolders\McKesson Surgery & Anesthesia\Crystal Reports\ProMedica Custom Reports\PHS PC\*.rpt";
          reportDest= @"C:\Program Files\McKesson\PHS\VER15.0\Reports";
          File.Copy(reportSource, reportDest);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Disables those due to a virus?" - That's highly suspicious.  It sounds like the problem is with another application/the task schedule on a machine, and not with task scheduler itself.

Task scheduler *is* the way to go here, there's no reason to *not* use it for periodic schedules (having it run your console application).

If you *must* have a service that does this, then don't rely on a timer, use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), as it has *very* rich support for scheduling tasks/jobs, etc. and was created specifically for this purpose.

In this particular case, a [`SimpleTrigger`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_5.html) instance would do, just give it the `repeatInterval` that you want your task to run on.

If you need to support the notion of "every Friday at noon" (which you need because of things like daylight savings time), then you want a [`CronTrigger`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html).

Once you have your trigger set up, it's a [simple matter of setting up the schedule and job](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html) to execute based on the firing of the trigger.

Comment: Our security department says that they disabled schtsk because of the Conflicker virus', we've been hit by it twice this year.  I'm not sure what that has to do with it but anyway I will give this a try and see what I can do with it.  Thanks!